# Get SUM of Unique Value in a collection

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking to get the SUM of unique values in an excel worksheet using VB.net.
I am using a collection
So far my code gets me the Distinct Values, however I'm stumped on the Count side of things.
I feel like I'm close, but something is missing...

> My data could look like:

```
Apple
Apple
Peach
Cherry
```

I'm looking for Results to be:

```
Apple 2 
Peach 1 
Cherry 1
```

This is where I am:

```
MySub:
        Dim c, r As Range
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim dc As New Collection
        Dim s As String

        For Each c In r
            dc.Add(c.Value, c.Value)
        Next c

        For i = 1 To dc.Count
            s = dc.Item(i)
        Next i
```

This produces my distinct list of values, but I'm not seeing how to obtain the SUM of those values.
Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: The descriptions for the VB.NET and VB6 tags explicitly state that they are different languages and not to use each for the other. If you're using VB.NET then you're not using VB6 so don't tag your question VB6.

Comment: If you're not using VB6 then don't use a `Collection` either. That's basically there for compatibility with upgraded VB6 code. You should be using a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)`.

Comment: As with all programming problems, you should be solving the problem first, then writing code to implement that solution. Think about how you would do this if it was a manual process. For each item in the original list, you'd first check whether it was in the final list. If it was not, you would add it and set the count to 1. If it was, you you would increment the existing count by 1. Not surprisingly, that's what you do in code too. Now your task is to specifically find out how to do those things, which you can do without asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this really is VB.Net, you could use a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)` like this:

```
Dim counts As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
For Each c In r
    If Not counts.ContainsKey(c.Value) Then
        counts.Add(c.Value, 0)
    End If
    counts.Item(c.Value) = counts.Item(c.Value) + 1
Next c

For Each pair In counts
    Debug.Print(pair.Key & " " & pair.Value)
Next
```

Comment: In the above, r = a range. I keep getting errors. can not convert string..any ideas? Thanks

Comment: In your code, you're using `c.Value` instead of `c`.  Code has been updated.

Comment: You nailed it. I figured it out a few minutes ago as well, was going to delete my comment, but instead figured I'd let you know you were spot on. Thanks a ton.